# Getting the name of the variable in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to get the name of the variables from a **List** that represents a **Value** of the **dictionary** so that i can fill a combo box.So far i have tried using **`nameof`** method but i cant't get the name.
In My example i would like to fill the combobox with `param1`,`param2`,`param3`
The const variables are in another class **Constants**.

```
        public const string param1 = "a";
        public const string param2 = "b";
        public const string param3 = "c";
        public const string d = "d";
        public const string e = "e";
        public const string f = "f";
```

The **dictionary** of lists containing constants

```
  public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> formIdDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                {singleParamFo,new List<string> {param1,param2,param3 } },
                {PIDFo,new List<string> {d,e,f } }
            };
```

The troublesome **foreach**

```
public SingleParamForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var t in Constants.formIdDict[Constants.singleParamFo])
                singleParamCombo.Items.Add(nameof(t));
        }
```

What type should i specify in the foreach since i cant use something like

```
foreach(nameof(var t) in ....)
```

Comment: At the moment you add the variables to an array/list/dictionary/anythingelse, these loose any info about name, they are just a copy, what you want is basically impossible.

Comment: It might be better to say that you are not adding the variables to the list; you are adding *their values*. Just the values, that's all. What should the combo box contents look like? Your goal is easily reachable, but there is absolutely no hope of reaching it by the means you thought of. So clarify your exact goal, and we'll get you there by the best means available.

Comment: The thing is i need to store the pair Value-Name of variable containing value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<string>` as the TValue of your Dictionary, either create a class with the name and the value or use a `List<Tuple<<string,string>>` with the nameof as item1 and the value as item1.

```
public static IDictionary<string, List<Tuple<string,string>>> formIdDict =
    new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>
    {
        {singleParamFo, new List<Tuple<string,string>>
            {
                 new Tuple<string,string>(nameof(param1), param1)                     //...
            }
    }



 foreach (var t2 in Constants.formIdDict[Constants.singleParamFo])
     singleParamCombo.Item.Add(t2.Item1);
```

Then just refactor Tuple into a class with meaningful names

Comment: Thank  you for your suggestion i have chosen the class approach.